# android- unknown break out on api 21+

Tags: android, android-debug

I get this error in my application . It's working fine on android api below 21 but on api 21+, I get this error and I couldn't understand what is the problem .

this is the logcat:

```
    11-23 11:01:27.300 5127-5161/com.parslottery.parslottery E/rsC++: RS CPP error (masked by previous error): Allocation creation failed
11-23 11:01:27.300 5127-5161/com.parslottery.parslottery E/rsC++: RS CPP error (masked by previous error): Allocation creation failed
 A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 5161 (RenderThread)
 *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
 UUID: cfde7629-220e-4976-8f50-afa7067df33a
 Build fingerprint: 'Sony/D6503/D6503:6.0.1/23.5.A.1.291/2769308465:user/release-keys'
 Revision: '0'
 ABI: 'arm'
 pid: 5127, tid: 5161, name: RenderThread  >>> com.parslottery.parslottery <<<
11-23 11:01:27.404 408-408/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x14
11-23 11:01:27.426 408-408/? A/DEBUG:     r0 00000000  r1 9fe98efc  r2 9fe98ecc  r3 00000004
11-23 11:01:27.426 408-408/? A/DEBUG:     r4 aeb0bfa8  r5 9fe98efc  r6 9fe98f5c  r7 9f4bf600
11-23 11:01:27.426 408-408/? A/DEBUG:     r8 9fe98efc  r9 00000001  sl 00000001  fp 00000001
11-23 11:01:27.426 408-408/? A/DEBUG:     ip b5e36a70  sp 9fe98eb8  lr b5df93d1  pc b59e9926  cpsr 80030030
11-23 11:01:27.439 408-408/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
11-23 11:01:27.439 408-408/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00013926  /system/lib/libRScpp.so (_ZN7android3RSC19ScriptIntrinsicBlur8setInputENS0_2spINS0_10AllocationEEE+13)
    #01 pc 000333cd  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #02 pc 00033913  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #03 pc 0005ee6f  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #04 pc 0004481f  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #05 pc 00044ff1  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #06 pc 0002a53b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #07 pc 00027bdd  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #08 pc 00028a8f  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #09 pc 0003ed3d  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #10 pc 0001a67b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #11 pc 0001c417  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #12 pc 0001f43d  /system/lib/libhwui.so (_ZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread12RenderThread10threadLoopEv+80)
11-23 11:01:27.441 408-408/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 0001006d  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+112)
11-23 11:01:27.441 408-408/? A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 0005faf7  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+70)
11-23 11:01:27.441 408-408/? A/DEBUG:     #15 pc 0003f5af  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+30)
11-23 11:01:27.441 408-408/? A/DEBUG:     #16 pc 00019c97  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
11-23 11:01:28.158 408-408/? A/DEBUG: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_09
11-23 11:01:28.159 408-408/? E/DEBUG: AM write failed: Broken pipe
11-23 11:01:28.184 352-352/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/5127/oom_score_adj; errno=22
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Based on your segfault, you may want to look at how you are using Renderscript. Specifically how much memory are you allocating with a `Allocation`. If you are testing on device - it may be that the API 21+ device(s) is trying to work on larger bitmaps.

Comment: do you use special .so library?

Comment: Have you solved this?